# jqueryでの1文字ずつのアニメーションについて

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

ジェイクエリーの1文字ずつのテキストアニメーションで複数行対応する方法で困っています
splitで1文字ずつ配列にいれてforeachで配列をspanでくくりアニメーションさせているのですが
brタグなども1文字ずつ格納されてしまうためbrタグは1文字で格納されないようにしたいのですが方法がわかりません
欲を言えばbrタグのみではなくhtmlタグは1文字で配列に格納されずにしたいです。
また、foreachで回してspanを取り付ける方法ではなくて
htmlにspanを書く方法だと簡単に実装できるかと思うのですが毎回1文字ずつspanで囲むのが大変になるので、できればしたくありません。
初めて投稿するため勝手がわかりませんが、今現在このような感じです。
どなたかいいやり方ご教授いただけると助かります。
https://codepen.io/eqnu7zplnsaq9gl/pen/PBLpPm

```js
$(function() {
  var text = $(".text_animate").html();
  /*var html_tags = /<\/?[^>]+>/;
  var text_split=text.split(html_tags);*/
  var text_split = text.split("");
  $(".text_animate").html("");

  function animate() {
    text_split.forEach(function(val) {
      /*console.log(val);*/


      $(".text_animate").append("<span>" + val + "</span>");

    });

  }
  animate();
  $(window).load(function() {
    $(".text_animate span").each(function(index) {
      $(this).css({
        transitionDelay: index * 0.6 + "s"
      }).addClass("text_animate_on");
    });
  });




});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/*.text_animate{
 display: none;
}*/

.text_animate span,
.test_animate span {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.text_animate span.text_animate_on,
.test_animate span.text_animate_on {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.text_animate.text_animate_rotate span,
.text_animate_rotate.test_animate span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

.text_animate.text_animate_rotate span.text_animate_rotate_on,
.text_animate_rotate.test_animate span.text_animate_rotate_on {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.text_animate.text_animate_size span,
.text_animate_size.test_animate span {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.text_animate.text_animate_size span.text_animate_size_on,
.text_animate_size.test_animate span.text_animate_size_on {
  font-size: 10px;
}


/*部分的に変更したいときにextend使用サンプルここから*/

.test_animate.test_animate_size_on span {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.test_animate.test_animate_size_on span.test_animate_size_on {
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*部分的に変更したいときにextend使用サンプルここまで*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text_animate">te<br>st</p>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/EqnU7ZPlNsAq9Gl/items/5dc33636ea8f8f363828

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/141087

Comment: teratailにて解決されているようですが、こちらの質問も解決した内容を自己回答し承認してください。(ついでに言うなら、マルチポストする場合はポストした全ての投稿に対して解決した内容のフォローをいれてください。それが出来ないならマルチポストはするべきではないです）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

splitに正規表現を組み合わせてできるかと思います。
確認用に以下をご確認くださいませ。
codepenにあったコードに対して手を加えておりますので。
そのまま動くかと思います。

```js
$(function(){
 var text=$(".text_animate").html();
 var text_split=text.split(/(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/);
 $(".text_animate").html("");
 function animate(){
   text_split.forEach(function(val){
  /*console.log(val);*/
  
  
   $(".text_animate").append("<span>"+val+"</span>");
  
 });
 
 }
 animate();
 $(window).load(function(){
  $(".text_animate span").each(function(index){
  $(this).css({transitionDelay:index * 0.6 +"s"}).addClass("text_animate_on");
 });
 });
 
 
  
 
});
```

```css
/*.text_animate{
 display: none;
}*/
.text_animate{
 span{
  transition: 1s;
 opacity: 0;
 &.text_animate_on{
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  
 }
 }
 &.text_animate_rotate span{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  &.text_animate_rotate_on{
   transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
 }
 &.text_animate_size span{
  font-size: 22px;
  &.text_animate_size_on{
   font-size: 10px;
  }
 }
}
/*部分的に変更したいときにextend使用サンプルここから*/
.test_animate{
 @extend .text_animate;
 &.test_animate_size_on span{
  font-size: 25px;
  &.test_animate_size_on{
   font-size: 15px;
  }
 }
}
/*部分的に変更したいときにextend使用サンプルここまで*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text_animate">te<br>st</p>
```